# HTML won't recognize my the javascript file I am asking it to run, SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (anonymous function)script.js:1

Tags: javascript, html

I have a very simple HTML file that looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

    <p>Words</p>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type ='text/javascript' src ="js/script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

And the file `script.js` is in a directory called `js` and that directory is located in the same directory as the HTML file. `script.js` looks like this:

```
function myFunction(){
    alert("Hello World");
}
```

The alert won't show up, and the console just says

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
(anonymous function)script.js:1
```

From debugging, this error seems to indicate that it can't find the file `script.js` though for the life of me I can't figure out why.

Comment: is that the exact stuff that exists in your script.js file???

Comment: `Unexpected token '<'` suggests that the response may include markup either with (e.g. ad injection) or instead of (e.g. error page) `function myFunction()`. Try inspecting the request for `js/script.js` under "Network" in your browser. When the request completes, what is its status code? If you look at the response received, does it match the file?

Comment: The content of your question does not lead to the answer. There doesn't appear to be anything here. Are you certain this is the full content of your script.js file?

Comment: Can you reproduce error at plnkr http://plnkr.co?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what is in my script.js file. Since it sounds like my implementation is correct for the files I mentioned, it sounds like the issue might possibly be in app.js.  Also I think I can figure some things out by checking the developer tools, but unfortunately I'm very new to web dev, so I'll have to learn more before I fully understand all aspects of the developer tools.

Comment: Also, I used Plunker, as someone recommended and my code works fine. Since I tried my code on, like 4 different browsers, I'm going to say it isn't a browser issue, so I'll chalk this error up to not knowing what the hell I'm doing with node.js and answer the question better when I understand it more fully and can fix it. Thank you everyone for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely there is something wrong resolving tour javascript file and the server returns HTML instead (most likely a 404 not found page).

You can diagnose this by checking the console of your browser (hit F12). Check the network tab and see if it loads okay.

After that, make sure the file exists, it is available directly from your browser, etc.